# Identify this frog from Bangladesh

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Description: About 5-6 in long

Time: March,2019 (summer)

Location: (Alutila Cave) Khagrachari, Bangladesh
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pleae provide approximate size of the specimen and time of year (month and season if possible). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. +1 for the post. Hope you get an answer! :)